# Finding data at a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where records for a user are stored

This includes columns `username`, `FromDate`, `ToDate`, `Status`

I have a requirement where I need to find the number of active users (status) on `1 Dec 2010` and on `1 April 2011`.

In other words we are trying to determine how many users were active on `1 Dec 2010` and `1 Apr 2011`, so that we can compare how many users have been added/lost.

How can this be done?

Comment: I need to add that for some users ToDate can be a date in future. as in 31-12-9999 . So I need to know the details as at 1 Dec 2010 and details as at 1 Apr 2011. Which means same users can be a part of both sets

Comment: Thanks Alex. so how do i tell how many customers were there on 1 Dec 2010 and how many on 1st Apr 2011

Comment: update my query to show added and removed users.

Answer (score 3):

Users that were active both on Dec 1 and Apr 1:

```
with cte
as
(
    select UserName, FromDate, ToDate
    from MyTable
    where Status = 'Active' -- adjust to your status type
)
select distinct UserName
from cte
where 
    FromDate < '20101202' 
    and ToDate >= '20101201' and
    UserName in
    (
        select *
        from cte
        where FromDate < '20110402' and ToDate >= '20110401'
    )
```

To see what users were added and what users where removed, you can do something like this:

```
with cte
as
(
    select UserName, FromDate, ToDate
    from MyTable
    where Status = 'Active' -- adjust to your status type
)
select UserName, sum(WasActiveOnDecFirst) WasActiveOnDecFirst, sum(WasActiveOnAprFirst) WasActiveOnAprFirst
from
(
    select 
        isnull(du.UserName, au.UserName) UserName,
        case when du.UserName is null then 0 else 1 end WasActiveOnDecFirst,
        case when au.UserName is null then 0 else 1 end WasActiveOnAprFirst
    from
    (
        select distinct UserName
        from cte
        where FromDate < '20101202' and ToDate >= '20101201'
    ) du
        full join
    (
        select distinct UserName
        from cte
        where FromDate < '20110402' and ToDate >= '20110401'
    ) au
        on du.UserName = au.UserName
) tt
group by UserName
with rollup
```

The result would look like this:

```
UserName             WasActiveOnDecFirst WasActiveOnAprFirst
-------------------- ------------------- -------------------
user1                1                   1
user2                1                   1
user3                1                   1
user4                0                   1
NULL                 3                   4
```

The last row is total user number.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @FromDate date = '20101201'
declare @ToDate   date = '20110401'

select
  count(case when @FromDate between FromDate and ToDate then 1 end) as CountFromDate,
  count(case when @ToDate   between FromDate and ToDate then 1 end) as CountToDate
from YourTable
where FromDate <= @ToDate and
      ToDate >= @FromDate and
      Status = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Please refer the answer provided by [**Mikael Eriksson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson). It looks much better than the query written by me.

If you have only two dates to compare, you could do something like this. Screenshot #**1** shows output of the below given query against sample data. Users `1`, `4`, `6` and `9` were active on **`2010-12-01`**. Users `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `7` and `8` were active on **`2011-04-01`**. Hence the count **4** and **6**.
.

```
DECLARE @Date1  DATETIME
DECLARE @Date2  DATETIME

SET @Date1 = '2010-12-01'
SET @Date2 = '2011-04-01'

    SELECT  @Date1          AS AsOnDate
        ,   COUNT(Username) AS ActiveCount
    FROM    dbo.Users
    WHERE   @Date1 BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
UNION
    SELECT  @Date2          AS AsOnDate
        ,   COUNT(Username) AS ActiveCount
    FROM    dbo.Users
    WHERE   @Date2 BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: Output]